# adjust latex columns so that text indents automaticaly

Tags: tables, multicolumn

only half of the table is shown  and I can't fix it 
 here is my script

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
%\label{my-label}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Approach}& \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{feature}}& \textbf{Cyc}  & \textbf{Usdhold \& King} & \textbf{Grüninger - Fox}& \textbf{KACTUS} & \textbf{METHONTOLOGY}& \textbf{SENSUS} & \textbf{On-To-Knowledge}     \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Use Process}}}&\multicolumn{3}{l|}{Projects where the methodology has been used}& High Performance Knowledge Bases (HPKB)& Entreprise Project& TOVE& KACTUS& MKBEEM, OntoWeb, Esperonto, founded Spanish projects: "Usos de Ontologías en la Gestión de Conocimientos", "Prototipos deOntologías para el Medio ambiente", GUME.& Military air campaign planning project inDARPA & On-To-Knowledge, OntoWeb, SemiPort, AIFB Website, COST action "Modeling Real-Property Transactions\\ \cline{2-11}& \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Acceptation by external organisations}& Not known& Universidad Politécnica de Cataluña & Not Known& Not known& It is the recommended methodology to ontology development by FIPA (Foundation for Intelligence Physical Agents).& Not known & VU Amsterdam (NL), Aidministrator (NL), CognIT as (NO), SwissLife (SL), EnerSearch (SW) BT (UK), Ontoprise GmbH (DE), DFKI Kaiserslautern (DE), Fraunhofer Institute for Integrated Publication and Information Systems (DE), FIZ Karlsruhe (DE) \\ \cline{2-11} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Ontologies created by the methodology}& Cyc& Enterprise Ontology& TOVE& Electrical network ontologies& - CHEMICALS- Monatomic Ions Ontology- Environmental Pollutants- Reference Ontology- Restructured KA2 ontologies- Silicate Ontology- Knowledge management ontologies (KM-LIA)- MKBEEM ontologies- OntoRoadMap ontologies- Esperonto ontologies & Military air campaign planning ontologies      & Skills Management @ SwissLife,Virtual Organization @ EnerSearch,OntoShare @ BT,OntoWeb Portal,AIFB Portal \\ \cline{2-11}

\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing the `l` column alignment specifiers to, for example `p{.6in}`, would, in theory, be a help.  However, your table has so much information as to even preclude that approach, even if one make s the font `\tiny`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes okay i'll edit the  script with less information

Comment: given the table is large why have you use `[ht]` to prevent it appearing on a page on its own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data are way to crowded.  But without restructuring the table, what I did was:

1. changed column alignment from `l` to `p{.8in}`
2. used `\RaggedRight` in final 3 columns
3. Added hyphenation points in `METH\-ON\-TOL\-OGY`
4. Resorted to `\tiny`
5. Reduced `\tabcolsep` to `1pt`

Here is the MWE.  While multi-column 2 (cols2-4) is wider than it need be for these data, the OP's earlier table data showed a need not to overcompress.  Obviously, one can narrow the earlier columns, using that space to expand the latter column widths.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
%\label{my-label}
\tiny\tabcolsep=1pt\relax
\begin{tabular}{|p{.8in}|p{.8in}|p{.8in}|p{.8in}|p{.8in}|p{.8in}|p{.8in}|p{.8in}|>{\RaggedRight}p{.8in}|>{\RaggedRight}p{.8in}|>{\RaggedRight}p{.8in}|}
\hline
\textbf{Approach}& \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\textbf{feature}}& \textbf{Cyc}  & \textbf{Usdhold \& King} & \textbf{Grüninger - Fox}& \textbf{KACTUS} & \textbf{METH\-ON\-TOL\-OGY}& \textbf{SENSUS} & \textbf{On-To-Knowledge}     \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Use Process}}}&\multicolumn{3}{l|}{Projects where the methodology has been used}& High Performance Knowledge Bases (HPKB)& Entreprise Project& TOVE& KACTUS& MKBEEM, OntoWeb, Esperonto, founded Spanish projects: "Usos de Ontologías en la Gestión de Conocimientos", "Prototipos deOntologías para el Medio ambiente", GUME.& Military air campaign planning project inDARPA & On-To-Knowledge, OntoWeb, SemiPort, AIFB Website, COST action "Modeling Real-Property Transactions\\ \cline{2-11}& \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Acceptation by external organisations}& Not known& Universidad Politécnica de Cataluña & Not Known& Not known& It is the recommended methodology to ontology development by FIPA (Foundation for Intelligence Physical Agents).& Not known & VU Amsterdam (NL), Aidministrator (NL), CognIT as (NO), SwissLife (SL), EnerSearch (SW) BT (UK), Ontoprise GmbH (DE), DFKI Kaiserslautern (DE), Fraunhofer Institute for Integrated Publication and Information Systems (DE), FIZ Karlsruhe (DE) \\ \cline{2-11} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Ontologies created by the methodology}& Cyc& Enterprise Ontology& TOVE& Electrical network ontologies& - CHEMICALS- Monatomic Ions Ontology- Environmental Pollutants- Reference Ontology- Restructured KA2 ontologies- Silicate Ontology- Knowledge management ontologies (KM-LIA)- MKBEEM ontologies- OntoRoadMap ontologies- Esperonto ontologies & Military air campaign planning ontologies      & Skills Management @ SwissLife,Virtual Organization @ EnerSearch,OntoShare @ BT,OntoWeb Portal,AIFB Portal \\ \cline{1-11}

\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable} 


\end{document}
```

[image]